# Custom LINQ provider calling an asynchronous, generic method with reflection fails when getting the Task.Result object

Tags: c#, linq, generics, asynchronous

I am trying to build a LINQ provider to a well defined web API with a well defined model. I am following these walkthroughs:

- [Part I](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattwar/2007/07/31/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-i/)
- [Part II](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattwar/2007/07/31/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-ii/)

It was going well until it got to the part when all the pieces needed to be put together so the provider has a non generic Execute method within which an asynchronous method of a custom HTTPRequest class is invoked using reflection and that part works very well, the problem is that when trying to get the value of the Result property in the returned Task object it fails with a TargetException saying "Additional information: Object does not match target type.

This is the code where the exception happens, I don't think other pieces are relevant:

```
        public override object Execute(Expression expression)
        {
            var elementType = TypeSystem.GetElementType(expression.Type);

            var task = GetResult(expression, elementType);
            var resultProperty = typeof (Task<>).MakeGenericType(elementType).GetProperty("Result"); 

            //It fails here!
            var result = resultProperty.GetValue(task);

            return result;
        }

        private async Task GetResult(Expression expression, Type elementType)
        {
            var requestUrl = Translate(expression);

            var method = _httpRequest.GetType().GetMethod("GetHttpRequest").MakeGenericMethod(new[] { elementType });
            var task = (Task) method.Invoke(_httpRequest, new object[] { requestUrl });
            await task;
        }
```

I have been thinking that the object that needs to be returned should be an IEnumerable and what is coming out of the Result property is a single T and I am sure I will have to address this but I do not believe is the reason for the current exception.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `async Task GetResult` The returned task from that method is not the one that you `awaited`, hence has no result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get `Task<ElementType>.Result` property here:

```
var resultProperty = typeof (Task<>).MakeGenericType(elementType).GetProperty("Result");
```

And then you are applying it to object of type `Task` (note - not `Task<ElementType>`) which your GetResult returns. So you are passing object of wrong type to PropertyInfo.GetValue method, which results in exception you observe.

To fix, just do:

```
    private Task GetResult(Expression expression, Type elementType)
    {
        var requestUrl = Translate(expression);

        var method = _httpRequest.GetType().GetMethod("GetHttpRequest").MakeGenericMethod(new[] { elementType });
        var task = (Task) method.Invoke(_httpRequest, new object[] { requestUrl });
        return task;
    }
```

Now, despite GetResult still returns `Task`, we know that it's really is `Task<ElementType>` which you created (here I assume that _httpRequest.GetHttpRequest returns `Task<ElementType>`), and things should work out fine.

Comment: I see. So how do I cast the task variable to Task<ElementType> since I do not know what ElementType is at compile time?

Comment: You cannot cast it, because it's really of type Task. You await your Task<ElementType> at the end of GetResult, so you are losing the result. Just return task in GetResult without awaiting (why should you?).